# Submitting a form within Karma process => Some of your tests did a full page reload

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

In one angular directive, I have this code:

```
$('[name=' + formName + ']').bind('submit', function () {
   validate();
});
```

In the beforeEach clause of a Karma test, I have this code:

```
bootstrapInput = $compile('<form novalidate name="aForm">' +
            '<input-field icon="true" for="email">' +
            '<div>' +
            '<input class="form-control" class="email" name="email" id="email" type="email" ng-model="user.email" required />' +
            '</div>' +
            '<input-validation for="email" custom-error="custom error" required="Email is required" email="Email must be in valid format"/>' +
            '</input-field>' +
            '<button type="submit" value="valider" ></button>' +
            '</form>')($rootScope);
```

And in my unit test, I have this code:

```
it('should launch validation process if form has just been submitted', function(){
            bootstrapInput.submit();  //way of doing?
            expect(bootstrapInput.children().hasClass('has-error')).toBe(true);
});
```

But I got the following error:

```
Some of your tests did a full page reload!
```

The question is: How to provoke a submit event to process inside a Karma unit test, without making page reload?

Comment: Why don't you just use `ng-submit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue but I do a workaround using a click on the submit button.

```
bootstrapInput.find('input[type="submit"]').click();
expect(bootstrapInput.children().hasClass('has-error')).toBe(true);
```

Hope someone will find an explication to this.