# Karma/jasmine Angular directive submit click unit test failed while running in bunch, but not alone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I have a angular directive that has a `<form>` which has ng-submit bind to a function in directive controller. Standing up the code and running the unit test alone would work.

The problem is when running all of the unit tests, we would see behavior like

```
  PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
allMessages PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
```

Here is the unit test:

```
it('Verify submit button is clicked', function () {
            var btnSubmit = form.querySelector('#submit');                 
            btnSubmit.click();

            timeout.flush();
            expect(scope.blah).to.equal(blah);}
```

when i comment out  btnSubmit.click() everything would work.

Here is the html:

```
<paper-dialog modal class="pa-paper-dialog" id="blah" role="alertdialog">
    <paper-button 
        dialog-dismiss 
        class="close-button" 
        ng-click="resetPA(event)"> 

    </paper-button>
    <form class="blah" is="iron-form" ng-submit="submitFunction(blah)" method="get" action="/" id="form">
        <div class="pa-header">text</div>
        <div class="input-fields-panel"></div>
        <div class="buttons-panel">
            <button type="submit" class="blah" id="submit">Admit</button>
            <paper-button noink dialog-dismiss class="blah" ng-click="resetPA(event)">Cancel</paper-button>
        </div>
    </form>
</paper-dialog>
```

Any idea why?

thanks!

Comment: An HTML example may help here, but anyway - maybe this can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565968/submitting-a-form-within-karma-process-some-of-your-tests-did-a-full-page-rel

Comment: Sure! added in.

Comment: I think I came across the post before already; I think i am doing the same thing as the post did - just get the submit button in form and call .click()

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, but the `.click()` works in PhantomJS and not Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We end up taking another route to deal with this...

Instead of doing button click() for form submission, we try to access isolateScope and call the submit function directly in test.

```
var elem = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')(scope);
scope.$digest();
isolateScope = angular.element(elem).isolateScope() || angular.element(elem).scope();

scope.mySubmitfunction(blah blah);
```

In this way, we would not see any problem from unit test and all will pass.